# React native Flatlist doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, flatlist

I have an weather app in react native that uses `react-native-app-intro-slider` [that is basically a vertical FlatList](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-intro-slider). This is my App render

```
return (
<AppIntroSlider style = {{backgroundColor:'#4c669f'}} 
   renderItem = {_renderItem} 
   data = {dataToRender} 
   showDoneButton = {false} 
   showPrevButton = {false} 
   showNextButton = {false}/>
)
```

And the Slider items that i'm rendering look like this

```
_renderItem = ( {item} ) => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, marginTop:20, color:'white',fontSize:25, alignSelf:'center'}}>{item.name}</Text>

        <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', marginTop:15, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Image source={{uri: 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + item.icon + '@2x.png'}} style={{width:90, height:90}}/>
          <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:60}}>{`${_.round(item.temp)}°C`}</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
        <Text style={{alignSelf:'center', justifyContent:'center', color:'white', fontSize:20}}>{item.clouds}</Text>     
          <View style={{display:'flex', alignItems:'flex-start', marginLeft:40 }}>

          <View style={{ marginTop:40, flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <Icon name='wind' size={28}/>
              <Text style={{marginLeft:5, fontSize:22, color:'white'}}>{item.wind} km/h</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ marginTop:10, flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <Icon name='temperature-low' size={28} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:5, fontSize:22, color:'white'}}>{_.round(item.temp_min,1)} °C</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ marginTop:10, flexDirection:'row' }}>
              <Icon name='temperature-high' size={28} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:5, fontSize:22, color:'white'}}>{_.round(item.temp_max,1)} °C</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ marginTop:10, flexDirection:'row' }}>
              <Icon name='compress-alt' size={28} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:5, fontSize:22, color:'white'}}>{item.air_pressure} hPa</Text>
          </View>
          </View>
        </View>

          <View>
               <FlatList
                data={dataToRender16}
                renderItem={renderFlatListItem}/> 
          </View>
        
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And the issue is that the FlatList in the rendered item (in the second code snippet) is not scrolling down, I've tried changing some styles but none of that worked

Answer (score 0):

First of your **dataToRender16** must have some unique id ,and you must add **keyExtractor** to your **FlatList**.
checkout the following example:

```
  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    data={dataItems}
    renderItem={itemData => (
      <ItemComponent
        id={itemData.item.id}
        onDelete={removeItemHandler}
        title={itemData.item.value}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: And what to do after that to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flex:1` to styles of the  that FlatList is netsted is solved the issue

```
          <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', paddingTop:50}}>
               <FlatList
                data={dataToRender16 }
                renderItem={renderFlatListItem}/>        
          </View>
```